# Missed method in Xamarin Android class (RoundedBitmapDrawable)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I can see in in the Android documentation that it has a library to round corners etc etc, it is RoundedBitmapDrawable , and I see it has a setCircular method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html#setCircular(boolean)

I see that Class in Xamarin Android. But I cant find this method or something like that (Circular, SetCircular), class is in the Xamarin Android support Library: https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv4-18

Anybody know why or if am I wrong? Has Xamarin Android library a 1:1 equivalence with Android or there a lot of cases like that?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be 1:1; if it doesn't exists it probably hides under a bit different name. If it really doesn't exist, try this: http://trailpoint.com/round-corners-of-a-bitmap-in-xamarin-android/

Comment: Thanks Artur. I have searched for different names as well and I know there are another ways to do it. Maybe somebody knows why in this case api is not 1:1

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for it too and figured out it's not actually a method, but an attribute you have to set :

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmap = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.Create(getResources(), bitmap);
roundedBitmap.Circular = true;
```

As you can see on the screenshot, you can set `CornerRadius` as well, there's no `setCornerRadius` method.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XU8d.jpg)